# How to connect two different networks hosted on 2 different NICs

Tags: routing, ip, nic

I have a Windows 2012 R2 server which has 4 NICs. Two of these NICs are connected to seperate private networks(not connected to internet). NIC3 is connected to 192.168.137.1 (Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0) and NIC4 to 192.168.1.1(same subnet mask). All the PCs in NIC3 and NIC4 are configured with static IPs corresponding to the network they are in.

I want to access a printer on NIC4 (IP: 192.168.1.200) from my PC in NIC3 having IP: 192.168.137.171. I am unable to ping the printer.

I have tried everything from bridging the connections of NIC3 and NIC4 to enabling sharing of Internet connection of NIC4 with NIC3. Nothing works. What can be done here?

Comment: Assuming your computers are connected to a local switch, you should add a static route on your switch, otherwise you won't be able to access one network from the other one

Comment: How can I do that? I dont think we have managed switches

Comment: I don't know your actual setup from there so it's pretty hard to say. They should be connected somehow right. Your network has to has a gateway defined right for each of your subnets...

Comment: The gateways are taken by default as I have left them blank on the configuration of NIC3 and NIC4 cards on server

Comment: Who's responsible for providing the gateways? There should be a computer or a server or a switch or whatever that is doing that....

Comment: I just checked on my PC in NIC3 has the default gateway same as the IP address of NIC3 configured in server(192.168.137.1). I think the default gateway is the same as IP of NIC based on the network you are in

Comment: Enable routing on the server then set the default gateway of all machines to be the IP address of each corresponding NIC on the server. https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/how10169/configuring-windows-server-2012-r2-as-a-router?lang=en you just don’t want to use NAT between the two networks. You can also use the server as a DHCP server so you can get rid of those god forsaken static IP addresses.